# Django ModelForm: Insert blank choice into many form fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In order to be sure I force users to pick a valid value from a dropdown (rather than unknowingly leaving the first option in the list set without changing it to the correct value), I am inserting the blank choice field in many required form fields.

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=False, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='')
```

**Original forms.py (Explicitly defining the form field.  This works.)**

```
from django.db.models.fields import BLANK_CHOICE_DASH
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    gender = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=True, choices=BLANK_CHOICE_DASH+MyModel._meta.get_field('gender').choices)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now, because I am doing this for many fields, I tried to revise my earlier code in forms.py:

**Revised forms.py (Setting the choices in `__init__()`. Does not work.)**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for type in ('gender', ...):
            self.fields[type].choices.insert(0, (u'',u'---------' ))
    # Not needed anymore.. replaced by code in __init__()
    # gender = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=True, choices=BLANK_CHOICE_DASH+MyModel._meta.get_field('gender').choices)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

In this case, I do not get the dashes as the first choice in the dropdown.

I tried to look into the problem by using `pdb` in the template to inspect the form field right before it was outputted.  The debugger shows `element.field.choices` to be `(u'', u'---------'), ('f', 'Female'), ...]` in *both* cases.  Nevertheless, the code that outputs the form field inserts the dashes only in the original code, not in the revised code.

I tried stepping through the Django code that renders the form field to figure out if it was using some other field besides `.choices` that I'm not aware of, but I never stepped into the right part of the code.

How can I accomplish this?  Although it works fine the first way, the revised code is much more DRY. If only I could make it work!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using the built-in [`empty_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label)?

Comment: @solarissmoke Because the empty choice isn't showing up by default because of the way the model is written.  Hence the need to force in the empty choice.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in `ChoiceWidget.__deepcopy__()`.

These work:

```py
# self.fields[name].choices.insert(0, (u'', u'---------'))
self.fields[name].widget.choices.insert(0, (u'', u'---------'))
# or
self.fields[name].choices = BLANK_CHOICE_DASH + self.fields[name].choices
```

## Explanation

`TypedChoiceField.choices`, inherited from `ChoiceField`, is a `property`:

> ```py
> class TypedChoiceField(ChoiceField):
> ```
>
> ```py
> class ChoiceField(Field):
>     ...
>
>     def _get_choices(self):
>         return self._choices
>     
>     def _set_choices(self, value):
>         # Setting choices also sets the choices on the widget.
>         # ...
>         if callable(value):
>             value = CallableChoiceIterator(value)
>         else:
>             value = list(value)
>     
>         self._choices = self.widget.choices = value
>     
>     choices = property(_get_choices, _set_choices)
> ```

- `_set_choices()` assigns `self.widget.choices` in addition to `self._choices`.

  - The widget `choices` is the one used in the rendering.
  - The widget `choices` is supposed to be the same instance as that in the field.

The field and widget are deepcopy'ed as follows:

> ```py
> class ChoiceField(Field):
>     widget = Select
>     ...
>
>     def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
>         result = super().__deepcopy__(memo)
>         result._choices = copy.deepcopy(self._choices, memo)
>         return result
> ```
>
> ```py
> class Select(ChoiceWidget):
> ```
>
> ```py
> class ChoiceWidget(Widget):
>     ...
>
>     def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
>         obj = copy.copy(self)
>         obj.attrs = self.attrs.copy()
>         obj.choices = copy.copy(self.choices)
>         memo[id(self)] = obj
>         return obj
> ```

- `ChoiceWidget.__deepcopy__()` does not `memo`ize the copy of `self.choices`.

  - The copy of `choices` is then unavailable to the `deepcopy` in `ChoiceField`.
  - The widget `choices` is no longer the same instance as that in the field.